# can you write a program to auto-update my facebook post?

Tags: facebook, scripting, edit

I was wondering if I could write a program / short script (though I feel like this can hardly be accomplished by a script or two) that would automatically edit my facebook post every 10 minutes? So, say I have a facebook post saying

> "the time right now is 9:40am"

Could I write a program for the post to be automatically updated to

> "the time right now is 9:50am"
>
> "the time right now is 10:00am"

...
and so forth? for a given period? (say for 2 days?)

Is this an achievable task? Would I need to deal with OAuth and such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve is definitely not allowed on facebook, and not possible either. Every single message must be 100% user generated, prefilling is not allowed and you would need to get the `publish_actions` permission approved by Facebook - which will not happen for stuff that is not allowed, obviously. More information can be found in the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) and in the official [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs).